# How do I set the width of a View using a variable created in a lifecycle method in react native?

Tags: variables, react-native, flexbox

I want to adjust the width of a  based on something that happens in ComponentWillMount.  I hardcoded a value inside the method and then attempted to use the variable inside my style object.  However, I received an error 'something' is not defined.

```
class Alarm extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        // const batteryPercentage = 55;
        console.log('check');
        const something = 44;
    }
}
```

my style object looks like this

```
const styles = {
    mainContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flex: 1,
        width: `${something}%`
    },
};
```

How do I get access to the variable 'something' that I created inside componentWillMount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your calculated value (`something`) into `state` then use array notation in `style` property to provide the value for `width`, like

**Sample**

```
<View style={[styles.mainContainer, { width: this.state.something }]} >
  ...
</View>
```

You can remove `width` from `mainContainer` or set it to a default value.

Hope this will help!

Comment: That was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Сan you like this solution with styled-components

```
    class Alarm extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          defaultWidth: 44;
        }
      }


      render() {
        return (
          <MainContainer width={this.state.defaultWidth} />
        );
      }
   }
```

And styled-component component

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const MainContainer= styled.View`
  width: ({ width }) => width,
`;
```

Comment: see more at [https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native)